# Only using MapKit for one city

Tags: iphone, routes, mapkit, city

I am not really too sure how to word this into google, so I will attempt to ask it here. I am attempting to use the MapKit to display different routes on a map for **only one city**. Is there a way to limit the amount of the World Map that can be used in the API?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this to viewDidLoad:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region={{0.0,0.0,},{0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = 30.44;
region.center.longitude = -84.31;
region.span.latitudeDelta=0.03;
region.span.longitudeDelta=0.03;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[mapView setDelegate:self];
```

it will center around the lat and long, with the magnification specified by the latDelta and longDelta. The lower those values are, the closer you will be zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` will notify its delegate whenever the map is scrolled (via delegate methods `-mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` and
`– mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`). Perhaps you could write some code in those methods to check and see whether the user has scrolled outside of the city, and if so, use `setRegion:animated:` to move the map back into the correct bounds.